# How store $http get response in variable accesible from outside $http function (Angularjs)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, http-get

I'm still learning angular and javascript and I find stack
overflow really helpful. Actually this is first time I couldn't find solution to my problem in other questions & answers here. I tried many solutions, but nothing is working for me.

In short: I want to save response from $http get (user data) in variable, so I could use it in other functions in this controller.

My factory with $http get function:

```
    app.factory('getUserFactory', ['$http', function($http){ 
    return {
        getUserData : function(email, password) {
            return $http.get('https://xxxxxxx.xxx.xx/api/v1/user/', {
            headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Basic '+ window.btoa(email +':'+password)
            }                
            });
        }            
    };
}]);
```

My controller with functions:

```
 app.controller('UserController', ['$scope','$http', 'getUserFactory', function($scope, $http, getUserFactory) {

 var user= {};    //Used to bind input fields from html file
 $scope.user= user;  

 $scope.userData = {}; // <-- HERE I WANT TO STORE RESPONSE

 $scope.logIn = function() {  // function runs on click

        getUserFactory.getUserData(user.email, user.password).success(function(response){

        $scope.userData = response.objects[0];                                  
        });            
 };
```

And simple on click function I use to test if it's working:

```
 $scope.consoleLog = function () {
        console.log($scope.userData);
    };
```

I assume my problem is connected with asynchrony of javascript, but I always call $http get first (user clicks 'log in' button) and then I try to use response to display user details. But outside `$scope.logIn()`, `$scope.userData` becomes an empty object again.

Comment: why you wanna store that response ?

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr?This will help arrive to a solution much quicker.

Comment: is "consoleLog" method in the 'UserController' ?

Comment: I want to store response so I can display response details (like username) on site and to use response details in other functions like $http patch  - so that user wouldn't have to write username again

Comment: 'consoleLog() is method in 'UserController'

Comment: @Emilia - it is hard to help without a plunker in this case but for starters, .success has been deprecated in favor of . then.  I did a quick plunker an it works with .then but not .success.  Additionally, I would say that you should be expecting response.data rather than response.objects[0]

Comment: Where are you actually calling $scope.login from?

Comment: @Emilia Okk so there is a better way of doing it what you are saying. you have to create a session and then create an api call to return loggedin user information. Then there will be no need of storing user related data on browser side

Comment: @HassanMehmood the advice you're giving here is really off-base for Angular.  Much of the point of a SPA is to avoid needing to repeatedly roundtrip to the server for the same data -- session data is typically handled in clientside services or factories (i.e. in browser memory) rather than as server sessions.

Comment: @Emilia Have you confirmed that your `.success()` is actually being called and that the data you want is really in `response.objects[0]`?  As written, assuming `consoleLog()` is on the same scope, it should be returning whatever you put into `$scope.userData`.    You may be better off cacheing the user data inside a service rather than in an individual controller, however, so you can more easily get at the data from elsewhere in your app -- `getUserFactory.getUserData()` could resolve with cached data immediately, for example, if it's already got it, and make the http call if not.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are calling login method in onclick.just try this:;

```
$scope.logIn = function() {  // function runs on click

    getUserFactory.getUserData(user.email, user.password).then(function(response){

    $scope.userData = response.objects[0];  

    });
```

};